# Can't apply Geopy's raw() method to a Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, geopy

I have a Pandas dataframe, and I'm calling a geopy function on each row of **'address_original'** column to get as much detail as possible about every address

```
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3

geolocator = GoogleV3(api_key='', timeout=5,)

df['full_address_geocoded'] = df['address_original'].progress_apply(geolocator.geocode())
print df['full_address_geocoded'][:5]

0    (Veale Rd, New Plymouth, New Zealand, (-39.095...
1    (Veale Rd, Delaware, USA, (39.8036422, -75.494...
2    (1068 Clearwater Valley Rd, Clearwater, BC V0E...
3    (1605 Pine St W, Stillwater, MN 55082, USA, (4...
4                                                 None
```

The issue is that I need more information than there is included when using geocode method. Geopy also has .raw property, which works perfectly on a single string and outputs the data about what region the address belong to, area, etc.

```
places = '1238 Davie St, Vancouver, BC'


geolocator = GoogleV3(api_key='AIzaSyBlNIvZTk-BpWDeX1FFXPbx6QwbNzZL80w')
location = geolocator.geocode(places, language='en')
print location.raw

{u'geometry': {u'location_type': u'ROOFTOP', u'bounds': {u'northeast': {u'lat': 50.6539919, u'lng': -120.3383232}, u'southwest': {u'lat': 50.6538198, u'lng': -120.3386968}}, u'viewport': {u'northeast': {u'lat': 50.6552548302915, u'lng': -120.3371610197085}, u'southwest': {u'lat': 50.6525568697085, u'lng': -120.3398589802915}}, u'location': {u'lat': 50.6539239, u'lng': -120.3385242}}, u'address_components': [{u'long_name': u'142', u'types': [u'street_number'], u'short_name': u'142'}, {u'long_name': u'Waddington Drive', u'types': [u'route'], u'short_name': u'Waddington Dr'}, {u'long_name': u'Upper Sahali', u'types': [u'neighborhood', u'political'], u'short_name': u'Upper Sahali'}, {u'long_name': u'Kamloops', u'types': [u'locality', u'political'], u'short_name': u'Kamloops'}, {u'long_name': u'Thompson-Nicola', u'types': [u'administrative_area_level_2', u'political'], u'short_name': u'Thompson-Nicola'}, {u'long_name': u'British Columbia', u'types': [u'administrative_area_level_1', u'political'], u'short_name': u'BC'}, {u'long_name': u'Canada', u'types': [u'country', u'political'], u'short_name': u'CA'}, {u'long_name': u'V2E 1N3', u'types': [u'postal_code'], u'short_name': u'V2E 1N3'}], u'place_id': u'ChIJaV6wtDgsflMR1J9ReM0lzLs', u'formatted_address': u'142 Waddington Dr, Kamloops, BC V2E 1N3, Canada', u'types': [u'premise']}
```

Here's a sample of the dataframe

```
print df.info()
print type(df)
print df['address_original'][:5]
print type(df['address_original'])

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2679 entries, 0 to 2678
Columns: 111 entries, access to zoning
dtypes: object(111)
memory usage: 2.3+ MB
None
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

0                 184,VEALE ROAD, Canada
1                 124,VEALE ROAD, Canada
2    1068,CLEARWATER VALLEY ROAD, Canada
3               1605,PINE STREET, Canada
4         1425,LOPEZ CREEK DRIVE, Canada
Name: address_original, dtype: object
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

The raw method doesn't work on multiple values, however, I get the TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable.

What is a way around this?

Comment: can you add a sample of the dataframe

Comment: @MadhurYadav better now?

Comment: `raw` is not a method. It's a property which returns a dict.

Comment: @KostyaEsmukov you're correct, I'll edit the question. Do you happen to know how to solve the problem?